# Add Image inside Div using ASP.NET c# - Repeater

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, repeater

I am trying to add an image inside a `div` which is present in repeater control from code behind.

```
<div id="dvimage"
     runat="server"
     style="width:20px;float:right;margin-right:22%;margin-top:-18px;">
  </div>
```

Inside above `div` I am trying to add an image using inner HTML property:

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in dtlViewUser.Items)
{
    HtmlGenericControl sortImagedv = item.FindControl("dvimage") as HtmlGenericControl;
    string imgupdated=  "<img id=\"imgupdated\" src=\"Images/active.png\"  alt=\"updated\" />";
    sortImagedv.InnerHtml = imgupdated; 
}
```

`div` is not rendered with the Image.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a new image object and including it in the DIV's control collection:

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in dtlViewUser.Items)
{
    HtmlGenericControl sortImagedv = item.FindControl("dvimage") as HtmlGenericControl;
    HtmlImage image = new HtmlImage();
    image.Src = "Images/active.png";
    image.Alt = "updated";
    image.ID = "imgupdated";

    sortImagedv.Controls.Add(image);
}
```

Comment: I got it I am doing wrong i.e. bind the data again after the record update that's why repeater control div get its initial state.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Label inside your DIV:

```
<div id="dvimage" runat="server" ... >
    <asp:Label ID="lblImage" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

And from your code-behind:

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in dtlViewUser.Items)
{
    Label lblImage = item.FindControl("lblImage") as Label;
    string imgupdated = "<img id='imgupdated' src='Images/active.png'  alt='updated' />";
    lblImage.Text = imgupdated;
}
```

### Updated: Or alternatively use [ItemDataBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx) event:

```
protected void dtlViewUser_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    // This event is raised for the header, the footer, separators, and items.

    // Execute the following logic for Items and Alternating Items.
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || 
        e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        string imgupdated = "<img id=\"imgupdated\" src=\"Images/active.png\"  alt=\"updated\" />";

        ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblImage")).Text = imgupdated;
    }
}
```

Comment: still not rendering on the browser. I had tried display none,and block property of div but unable to get what I want.

Comment: Make sure you are using Repeater Or DataList. And then try in in ItemBound event.

Comment: you should use ItemDataBound event.